# How to call function from a two-level inherited class in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I got a main program in prog2.cpp

```
#include "stack1.h"
int main(void){
stack1 x(100); // Declare a stack1 x of length 100
......
}
```

And I need to call this stack1 from stack1.h, but this original function is from stack.h, with is a parent class of stack1.h:

```
class stack
{
....
public:
stack(int length);
....
}
```

stack1.h is now looking like this:

```
#include "stack.h"
class stack1: public stack{
...... //irrelevant code
}
```

Problem is stack1 x(100) got an error from MVS saying:

> Error: no instance of constructor "stack1::stack1" matches the argument list.

I've tried many ways to get rid of this but it always led to more problems. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the subclass's constructor's responsibility to invoke the superclass's constructor.

You need to declare a constructor in the `stack1` class that, basically, forwards its parameter to its superclass's constructor:

```
struct stack1: public stack {

   stack1(int n) : stack(n) {}

};
```

You're not really calling a function here. You're calling a constructor. The rules for constructors are different. Normally, there's no issue with using a subclass to invoke a method that's inherited from a superclass. This is straightforward. But in this case, it's not really a method, it's a constructor. Different rules apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use the constructor from the parent class you can use the `using` keyword.

```
class stack1 : public stack
{
    using stack::stack;//use all constructors of stack
    using stack::operator=; //use the assignment operators
};
```

However: keep in mind that this miht initialize the values differently than you expect.

Comment: sad that I could only use one tick.  both of you are giving the exact solution I want, thanks!